# Problem pointing to a variable in a structure in dynamic memory

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I cannot seem to be able to input values into the structure I already declared. I am not sure if it's a syntax or logical error.

I've already tried to change syntax but always end up with the same error.

```cpp
struct Book{

    string title;
    Book* next;
};

Book bookName;
Book author;


Book* add_node(Book* in_root){

    cout <<"Enter Book name \n";
    cin >> bookName.title;

    cout << "Enter author name \n";
    cin >> author;
    author = new Book();
    Book -> Book.next = author;
}
```

The error is encountered in this portion of the code:

```cpp
    cout << "Enter author name \n";
    cin >> author;
    author = new Book();
    Book -> Book.next = author;
```

Comment: It should be something along the lines of `next = new Book(); cin >> next->title;` when adding a new node.

Comment: @Habitate Yes thank you that fixes a lot of the syntax errors, however what it says that the variable `next` is not declared and I am not sure what type I should give it exactly.

Comment: Just a few considerations ... 1) Why is `author` outside of Book structure, 2) `add_node` doesn't seem to return nothing and 3) I would recommend using smart pointers instead of `new` as you need to declare a `destructor` and `delete` objects created with `new`.

Comment: @ignacio I want to store everything in the dynamic memory which is why I declared next as a pointer. Also, although I didn't include it, I will have another function `void delete_list(Book* in_root)` that will be used to delete all the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are a couple of logical errors inside the code.

- There is absolutely no need to have 2 books named `bookName` and `author` unless I'm misinterpreting their purpose.
- `Book ->` and `Book.next` is invalid logic, since you're telling it to operate on the data type `Book`, not an object of type `Book`.

The code of what you potentially wanted should look something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Book{
    string title;
    string author_name; // You potentially wanted this?

    Book* next;
};

// This function assumes that `current_node->next` is `nullptr`
// The reasons for this is that making it handle such cases might be too difficult for you yet.
Book* add_node(Book* current_book){
    if(current_book == nullptr){
        cout << "Cannot link a new book to an non-existant book!\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    Book* new_book = new Book();

    cout <<"Enter the book name\n";
    cin >> new_book->title;

    cout << "Enter the author name\n";
    cin >> new_book->author_name;

    new_book->next = nullptr;

    current_book->next = new_book;
    return new_book;
}

int main(){
    Book* book = new Book();
    book->next = nullptr;

    cout <<"Enter the name of the first book\n";
    cin >> book->title;

    cout << "Enter the name of the first book's author\n";
    cin >> book->author_name;

    add_node(add_node(book));

    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I didn't make the function handle cases when `current_book->next != nullptr` is because it would then require the usage of pointers to pointers.
If you're interested in it, here it is:

```cpp
Book* add_node_v2(Book* current_book){
    if(current_book == nullptr){
        cout << "Cannot link a new book to an non-existant book!\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    Book* new_book = new Book();

    cout <<"Enter the book name\n";
    cin >> new_book->title;

    cout << "Enter the author name\n";
    cin >> new_book->author_name;

    new_book->next = nullptr;

    // Move to the last book in the chain
    Book** ptr_to_next = &current_book->next;
    while(*ptr_to_next != nullptr){
        ptr_to_next = &(*ptr_to_next)->next; 
    }

    *ptr_to_next = new_book;
    return new_book;
}
```

Keep in mind that you will eventually have to `delete` all the books in the chain.